# Cypress - The plugins file is missing or invalid running on Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cypress

I add this import - `const { addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin } = require("cypress-image-snapshot/plugin");`
into file cypress/plugins/index.js.
And error is thrown while running on Docker:
`` Your `pluginsFile` is set to `/cypress/plugins/index.js`, but either the file is missing, it contains a syntax error, or threw an error when required. The `pluginsFile` must be a `.js`, `.ts`, or `.coffee` file. ``
It works perfectly when I'm running the specs locally but strangely it fail when they are runned on the docker image.

`

Comment: Please share you Dockerfile or docker-compose file, together with your build/run commands.

Comment: docker-compose.ci.yaml :
...
services:
  functional-tests:
    image: docker.../dbi__cypress--build:7.5.0-6
    entrypoint: >
      bash -c "./wait-for-it.sh -t 60 app:3000 -- ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --config testFiles='LP001 - Landing Page.feature'"
    volumes:
      - ./.tools/scripts/wait-for-it.sh:/wait-for-it.sh
      - ./cypress:/cypress
      - ./cypress.json:/cypress.json
      - ./specifications:/specifications
      - ./cypress-cucumber-preprocessor.config.js:/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor.config.js
      - ./node_modules:/node_modules
...

Comment: In my experience I had a lot of troubles using docker volumes (perhaps I just don't know how to use them properly), but I can never get right stuff installed on the right place (host vs container), so I simply use a Dockerfile, and copy and install all the things I need in the container before starting tests. Plus I'm not sure how well volumes scale when you introduce parallelisation...